# gpg: keyblock resource ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg’: resource limit

Tags: apt, dpkg, gnupg

No matter what I do, I get the following error:

```
gpg: keyblock resource ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg’: resource limit
```

The original error(Dutch)

**Original Dutch**

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De status informatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
0 pakketten opgewaardeerd, 0 pakketten nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 12 niet opgewaardeerd.
1 pakketten niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Door deze operatie zal er 0 B extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Instellen van apt (0.9.9.1~ubuntu3.1) ...
gpg: sleutelblok bronnen ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg’: resource limit
gpg: sleutelblok bronnen ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-themes.gpg’: resource limit
gpg: sleutelblok bronnen ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-tor-browser.gpg’: resource limit
gpg: sleutelblok bronnen ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//wfg-0ad.gpg’: resource limit
gpg: sleutelblok bronnen ‘/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//yorba-ppa.gpg’: resource limit
gpg: sleutel 437D05B5: “Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>” niet veranderd
gpg: sleutel FBB75451: “Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>” niet veranderd
gpg: sleutel C0B21F32: “Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>” niet veranderd
gpg: sleutel EFE21092: “Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>” niet veranderd
gpg: Totaal aantal verwerkt: 4
gpg:              Onveranderd: 4
dpkg: error processing apt (--configure):
 subproces installed post-installation script gaf een foutwaarde 2 terug
Fouten gevonden tijdens behandelen van:
 apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the original error in it's entirety:

**Google Translated**

```
sudo apt- get- f install
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
The status information is read ... Ready
0 packages upgraded , 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded .
1 not fully installed or removed.
Through this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used .
Setting up apt ( 0.9.9.1 ~ ubuntu3.1 ) ...
gpg : key block sources '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg' :resource limit
gpg : key block sources '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-themes.gpg': resource limit
gpg : key block sources '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-tor - browser.gpg ' : resource limit
gpg : key block sources '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//wfg-0ad.gpg': resource limit
gpg : key block sources '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//Yorba-ppa.gpg': resource limit
gpg : key 437D05B5 : "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg : key FBB75451 : "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg : key C0B21F32 : "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012 ) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg : key EFE21092 : "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012 ) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg : Total number processed : 4
gpg : unchanged : 4
dpkg : error processing apt (--configure) :
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error 2 back
Errors were encountered while processing :
 apt
E : Sub -process/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code ( 1 )
```

---

Things I tried to fix this:

- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get check`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt-get -f install`

And also: `sudo apt-mark hold apt; sudo apt-get -f install`

---

When trying to install anything i also get the following:

> WARNING: The following packages can not be authenticated!

Comment: please translate the error report.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, see my updated question!

Comment: I'm not sure but the following bugs seem to be related. They also contain some of the PPAs. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733028

Comment: Please run the command `sudo env LC_ALL=C apt-get -f install` to show the messages in English. An automatic translation of error messages back into English is more confusing than anything, because exact wording matters.

Comment: Are you still seeking an answer? I've run into this problem as well and I think it is a valid question. Do you need me to paste the error in English?

Comment: @RolandiXor you can post the english version, but i long upgraded to trusty

Comment: @blade19899 I have this problem on trusty.

Comment: The way I fixed it was removing ppas, and then deleting a few (unwanted) gpg files from /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d. I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 8):

If you pre-install the webupd8 team's y-ppa-manager your life is going to be easier

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo update && sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

You can then remove or backup the existing gpg's by executing:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you will see something like this :

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
```

This means that you will have to re-import all keys ...

Now launch the y-ppa-manager application

```
Click on Advanced
Select Try to import all missing GPG keys
```

BAM! You should be back in business with all your repos working correctly!

Comment: thanks man. thats did the trick. i don't get this limit anyway.

Comment: Why all the files in the folder and not just the one giving problem? Maybe  `sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution from @A.B. it didn't go well but I managed to do a modified one. I installed `y-ppa-manager`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo update && sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Launched it :

```
sudo y-ppa-manager
```

And then : Manage PPAs > removed all the PPAs containing `webupd8team`
(I had 4 of them ) and then closed the y-ppa=manager.

In console, I re-added them. Ex :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 -y
....
....
```

And I did a `sudo apt-get update` and all went smoothly. No errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following commands to install all the missing keys automatically :

```
sudo apt install add-apt-key -y
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '/InRelease:.*not available: NO_PUBKEY/{print "sudo add-apt-key "$NF}' | sh -x
```

Here is an example output :

```
+ sudo add-apt-key 4C1CBE14852541CB
gpg: requesting key 852541CB from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 852541CB: "Launchpad PPA for Panda Jim" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
OK
+ sudo add-apt-key 03647209B58A653A
gpg: requesting key B58A653A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key B58A653A: "Launchpad PPA for Unit 193" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
OK
```

Hope this helps.